# Test Next.js Link with React-testing-library - The link does not render as a <a> tag in the tests

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-testing-library

I am using Next js (13.0.5) and react-testing-library (13.4.0).

In my code I use the Next js link component with a single div as a child, that div contains a text.
I am wrapping my text in a div because I want to add an icon to that div and the Link component from "next/link" accepts only 1 child.

It looks like so:

```
import Link from "next/link";

export const SupportMenu = () => {
  return (
    <Link href={"mailto:support@test.cool"}>
      <div>Email us</div>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

I try to test this like so:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

import { SupportMenu } from "components/shared/layout/SupportMenu";

describe("SupportMenu", () => {
  test("It links to support@test.cool email address", () => {
    render(<SupportMenu />);

    // there is a link
    const link = screen.getByRole("link");
    // the link links to the support email address
    expect(link.getAttribute("href")).toBe("mailto:support@test.cool");
  });
});
```

It fails at `screen.getByRole("link")`, and when I look at the screen.debug() I can see that there is indeed no `<a>` tag to be found, it seems to be replaced by a `<div>`:
[image]

However my elements tree DOES show a `<a>` tag:
[image]

I am very confused at what is happening here.

Note that if I remove the `<div>` around the text, the tests pass :(

Does anyone know why react testing library does not see the next js link as a `link` when the child is wrapped in a div?

Comment: Can't reproduce it. It works fine for me. I use https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-jest

Comment: @LinDu I don't see a test file for a link role. I have the same problem as Anne. There is no link role for the link